# Http session Id same for all tabs in same browser

Tags: java, session, servlets

when I try to get the session id in servlet using `request.getsession().getId()`. I am getting the same session for multiple tabs.If this is the case, how we can handle session for different users from different tabs?

Comment: Isn't that how it suppose to work? A single session at a time on a single browser?

Comment: @RuncornYes its fine,now two users logging in from same browser but from different tabs,now i want to differentiate two users sessions,how to do this?if i follow session id both user will get same session,how to handle this?